# Value is 100 or 200 depending on a number of criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a function that will look at information from three different cells, and depending on the value, it will input either **100** or **200**.

The rules for the functions are simple:

- If cell B4 is less than 00:40, and cell B12 is equal or over 90 and cell B20 is equal or over 8, then add a 100.
- If cell b4 is less than 00:30, and cell B12 is equal or over 95 and cell B20 is equal or over 15, then add a 200.
- If either is not true, then leave blank, or a 0.

The current function I created looks like this:

```
`=OR((IF(AND(Values!B4<"(00,40,00)",Values!B12>="90",Values!B20>="8"),"100",""),IF(AND(Values!B4<"(00,30,00)",Values!B12>="95",Values!B20>="15"),"200","")))`
```

but I get a `#Value` with this function.

I do hope this is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need quotation marks around the digits.
2. Instead of your time value, try: TIME(0,40,0)
3. You do not need "Values!"

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes.

If "00:40" is time than it should be a number behind. Excel stores dates as number. Place 00:40 in a cell and change the number format to General. You will find the numeric value for the date. It is 0.0277777777777778. Or use the formula `=TIME(0,40,0)` instead.

If B4 is a full date (not only time) than instead of Values!B4 use:

```
=TIME(HOUR(Values!B4),MINUTE(Values!B4),SECOND(Values!B4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "" around numbers in excel also your OR condition was returning two "" which was problem.

Always use evaluate formula to check the results.

`=IF(AND(Values!B4<TIME(0,40,0),Values!B12>=90,Values!B20>=8),100,IF(AND(Values!B4<TIME(0,30,0),Values!B12>=95,Values!B20>=15),200,""))`

Comment: That did it Imran. Thanks